# Print To File From CMD.EXE

Tags: printing, dos, foxpro

I have an old FoxPro program which can send reports to my network printer via the LPT1 port but I would like to print a report to a file to document something. Is there a way to capture the LPT1 port and send its documents to a file? I have tried the Paperless Printer, Adobe PDF, and the Microsoft XPS Document Writer but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which version you're using, but you could try the SET PRINTER command:

> SET PRINTER TO output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7 or 8 you could:

Install a Generic/Text Only printer on the PC, set to print to FILE:
Share it.
Redirect LPT1 to the share. i.e. at the prompt:

net use lpt1 \mymachine\mysharedprinter /yes

That *sometimes* works.

If not I would investiate DosBox which is a free MS-DOS emulator designed primarily for old games. [This link](http://www.printfil.com/efaq32.htm) might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

DOSBox Megabuild supports printing from DOS applications

[Linkage](http://home.arcor.de/h-a-l-9000/)

Look in the dosbox.conf to set your configuration options. For printing options look in the [parallel] and [printer] sections of this file.

For example I set up a client to print from his DOS application to a printer elsewhere on the network. Works fine.